# Tmux: send-key to a specific pane, even after changing the layout

Tags: tmux

Scripting tmux (in a vim function, but could be applied to simple bash script), I can easily send command to a target pane with -t 1, for example.
This works fine, as long as I don't change the layout of the windows.

```
function! RunPython()
    let pycmd = systemlist('command -v python')[0]
    let filename = expand('%:p')
    silent! call system('tmux send-key -t 1 "' . pycmd . ' ' . filename . '" enter;')
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>p :call RunPython()<CR>
```

This -t 1 will stop working if I toggle the layout (for example, using Ctrl+b, Ctrl+o) as pane 1 will become pane 0 and vice versa.

Is there a way to refers/target to a specific pane, wherever it goes or moved to? Similar to referring/targeting a window?

Looked around for few days now, but couldn't find anything.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tmux man page:

> Sessions, window and panes are each numbered with a unique ID; session
> IDs are prefixed with a ‘$’, windows with a ‘@’, and panes with a ‘%’.
> These are unique and are unchanged for the life of the session, window
> or pane in the tmux server.

So to get the pane's id you can do:

```
tmux display-message -p "#{pane_id}"
```

and then use whatever the pane_id number is (predeced by a `%`) to send your
keys - assuming the pane_id was '2', then:

```
tmux send-keys -t %2 'echo hello world' ^M
```

Comment: If you add something like the following to your tmux.conf (on recent versions), it will enable a pane border that shows some info for each pane at the top of the tmux window, such as its index, ID, current command, etc (please forgive the lack of formatting in comments):

`pane-border-status top;`

`pane-border-format "#[fg=white]#{session_name}:#{window_index}.#{pane_index}#[default] #{pane_title}, cmd=#[fg=white]#{pane_current_command}#[default], pane_id=#[fg=white]#{pane_id}#[default], pane_tty=#[fg=white]#{pane_tty}#[default]"  
`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used tmux in a while (finally switched to a tiling wm) but, I think you could try using the `Mark` feature of tmux panes. It basically allows you to "mark" one panel (regardless of its position) and then recall it; could this perhaps help you?

Check the [tmux man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html).

<sub>*Since I haven't used this in a while, let me know if this information is wrong (not in front of a machine w/tmux to test this atm).*</sub>